# RegularExpressionValidator for word count that handles punctuation

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation, webforms

I thought I had a great regex for limiting the number of words entered into a TextBox, however I discovered, it fails when there is punctuation in the text.

How can I modify this regex (or use a different one) that correctly counts words that may be made up of several sentences or contain other symbols?

```
^(?:\b\w+\b[\s\r\n]*){1,10}$
```

This limits the words to 10.

Answer (score 0):

***I think this is the ONLY WAY it can be done.***
I would like to see a better way if it exists.

*(requires an atomic group)*

For Unicode:

`^\s*(?>[^\pL\pN]*[\pL\pN](?:[\pL\pN_-]|\pP(?=[\pL\pN\pP_-])|[?.!])*\s*){1,10}$`

Explained

```
 ^ 
 \s*     
 (?>
      [^\pL\pN]* [\pL\pN]           # Not letters/numbers, followed by letter/number
      (?:
           [\pL\pN_-]                    # Letter/number or '-'
        |  
           \pP                           # Or, punctuation if followed by punctuation/letter/number or '-'
           (?= [\pL\pN\pP_-] )
        |  
           [?.!]                         # Or, (Add) Special word ending punctuation
      )*
      \s* 
 ){1,10}
 $
```

For Ascii:

`^\s*(?>[\W_]*[^\W_](?:\w|[[:punct:]_-](?=[\w[:punct:]-])|[?.!])*\s*){1,10}$`

Expanded

```
 ^   
 \s* 
 (?>
      [\W_]* [^\W_] 
      (?:
           \w 
        |  
           [[:punct:]_-] 
           (?= [\w[:punct:]-] )
        |  
           [?.!] 
      )*
      \s* 
 ){1,10}
 $
```

Comment: So far the Ascii one seems to be working.  Time will tell as users start to type in their content.  Thanks.